# Unable to change ownership of files in live session

Tags: permissions, filesystems

My dad has a problem with a folder containing some PDF files. Recently he got an `initramfs` case (following an `/dev/sda1: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found` error message) when trying to boot . I ran `fsck` on the HDD where the OS and all user files are.

Now he has the same situation again. This time he asked me if he can check his files without booting so we went for a live OS (Xubuntu, just like the one installed on the HDD).

Most of the files are perfectly accessible except for several files and folders. Right now I am fighting with a directory that I made accessible for user `1000`. However the files inside (PDFs) keep being owned by `root`.

Here are the outputs of `ls -l` on the respective folder

```
drw-rw-r--  2 1000 1000      4096 Mar 13 15:15 Docs (1960-1971)
```

and files inside

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 1000 1000 19252914 Mar 13 15:15 'Doc 1960.pdf'
-rw-rw-rw- 1 1000 1000 17676448 Mar 13 15:15 'Doc 1962.pdf'
-rw-rw-rw- 1 1000 1000 22710713 Mar 13 15:15 'Doc 1970.pdf'
-rw-rw-rw- 1 1000 1000 20919025 Mar 13 15:15 'Doc 1971.pdf'
```

I am rather confused since `thunar` shows me the following for the folder

[image]

and files inside

[image]

I tried `chown 1000 *` and `chmod -R u=rw,g=rw,o=r <directory>` (since at the beginning the access was even more messed up) but I got as far as I've described above.

As a superuser (`sudo su`) I am able to open, delete, copy etc. the respective files. For a backup purpose this is more than enough but I am still interested in why this is happening.

Comment: You should try and identify _why_ he's getting these errors. For example, is he powering off without shutting down? Is the disk dying? Has he got a backup? If not, address that _now_.

Comment: We are making a backup. That's why we went for a live OS. After `initramfs` the system boots. I even ran the `smartctl` but nothing. Now again this boot problem. What's even worse is that - despite my recommendations - the OS was installed on the same partition where the user files are. Otherwise I would have just formatted the disk to see if it's not just some corrupted file somewhere that's creating the issues. In terms of powering off - shutdown is used.

Comment: You MUST have execute permission for your directories otherwise they won't allow you in. `find /path -type d -exec chmod a+x {} +`